# How can I WSUS and AV update and manage compliance reporting on air-gapped Windows boxen?

Tags: windows-7, wsus, configuration-management, wsus-offline

A.k.a "WSUS via Sneakernet?"

(Similar question asked in 2013 [here](https://serverfault.com/questions/537171/windows-updates-anti-virus-updates-for-air-gapped-hosts), but some key differences and no strong answers to that one.)

Most of my environment consists of AD-joined Windows 7 workstations; I'm managing updates through WSUS and EPO, and that's got enough automation and reporting to satisfy.

I have, however, a select population of machines that are not network connected and never will be.  At the expense of a little manual prep work, I can use USBs or CDs and [WSUSOffline](http://www.wsusoffline.net/) to deploy the windows updates, and just copy the AV updates -- but that gives me no real closing of the loop in reporting terms.

I can track and report based on completely manual log examination by eyeball and recording on paper, but that seems very Victorian.  (Edwardian, even.)  Is there any way that I can still use WSUS and EPO (or perhaps SCCM?) or some related process to unify the tracking and reporting?

Comment: I don't see how you can accomplish unified/centralized tracking and reporting if these machines aren't connected to a network. Can you connect them to an isolated switch/VLAN?

Comment: Not able to connect them even to an isolated network; if nothing else, the epoxy in the network jack would be challenging.  I suppose I was hoping there was a sneakernet way of moving the results back to the management server.